# Query to get the bounding geom returns empty

Tags: postgis

Uploaded the zipcodes shapefile from US Census, to the Postgis.Trying to get the zipcode for the given POINT, using the below query.

```
    select a.zcta5ce10 from cenzcta2010_feb12 a
    where ST_covers(a.geom,ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(29.7763478009 -82.276416060547)'))
```

Tried other variations too, ST_Contains etc. None of them returned. If this is relevant, the point is obtained from OpenLayers map with SRID 4326.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are querying somewhere in Antarctica, you need to supply an *x*, *y* coordinate (i.e., *long*, *lat*).

```
select a.zcta5ce10
from cenzcta2010_feb12 a
where ST_Within(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(-82.276416060547 29.7763478009)', 4326), a.geom)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but did not understand the remar k - 'need to supply an x,y coord' am I not supplying in my query? are you referring to the SRID argument?

Comment: Your question had `POINT(lat long)`, which is has the wrong axis order. You need `POINT(long lat)` (or `POINT(X Y)`)